# The reply-to field is populated with a number sometimes when sending mail

Tags: email, smtp

I'm having the following problem on site running 4.7.31 and I would like to know if anyone else is having it.

When sending an email from the contact summary screen, if the user picks their own address rather than one from the globally configured "From Addresses", the email gets sent with a number instead of a reply-to address in the reply-to field, and their name is not prefixed to the email address.

For example:

If I send from an address configured as a global from address, the email arrives with "from" set to `Global Name civicrm@example.com` and reply-to set to `global_name@example.com`. But if user John Smith picks his own address to send from, it gets sent as just `civicrm@example.com` and the reply-to field has a number in it, eg. `5443`. Whereas previously it would have been sent as from `John Smith civicrm@example.com` with reply-to `john.smith@example.com`

(Red herring: The address part of the "from" is always civicrm@example.com because that it what it uses to authenticate with the SMTP server, and Gmail won't allow sending from other addresses unless they have been manually verified)